# How to get font family name identify usable characteristics

Tags: fonts

I have some Futura fonts with strange font names.

```
FUCEB__.PFB
FUCEB__.PFM
FUTU07.TTF
futubd_.ttf
FUTUR.TTF
FUTUR01.TTF
FUTUR02.TTF
FUTUR06.TTF
FUTUR07.TTF
FUTUR08.TTF
FUTUR09.TTF
```

When I double click on those fonts (`FUCEB__.PFM`), it opens in Windows Font viewer with no information on font family. The font name changes to Futura Medium regular.

How can I use these random named fonts in a Latex Document?

**OS**: Windows 10

**Distribution**: TexLive 2015

**IDE**: Texnic Center (It's TexStudio now, not that it matters)

Please let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ttf file into \Windows\fonts and then run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura}
\begin{document}
Some text in normalfont 
\bfseries Some text in bfseries 
\itshape Some text in bfseries and italic
\end{document}
```

and look if the fonts were found.

Comment: I copied and pasted the above code as is. The output is a series of random characters (in futura) is
`R n l d s d w s h m m n q l ' k e n m s - R n l d s d w s h m a e r d q h d r - R n l d s`
and 3 latex font warnings
`font shape 'EU1/Futura(0)/bx/n' undefined
using 'EU1/Futura(0)/m/n' instead`

Comment: then try `\setmainfont{FUTUR.ttf}`

Comment: I have
`Futura Book Bold Italic.ttf
Futura Book Bold.ttf
Futura Book Italic BT.TTF
Futura Book.ttf`
should I try one of these?

Comment: I tried `\setmainfont{Futura Book.ttf}`
It worked!! There was no `\bfseries` and `\itshape`, though

same warnings...

Comment: @manucpp it is written in the fontspec documentation that if you select a font by file name like this you must also specify explicitely the bold and italic series via the `BoldFont=`, `ItalicFont=` keys. Like in cfr's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Herbert for a lead on this one!

1. Installed only the fonts that I needed (Preview and install)
2. Opened `cmd` and navigated to `c:\windows\fonts`
3. Listed all Futura fonts by executing `dir /b fut*.*`
4. `cmd` listed the fonts as

> ```
> C:\Windows\Fonts>dir /b fut*.*
> Futura Book Bold Italic.ttf
> Futura Book Bold.ttf
> Futura Book Italic BT.TTF
> Futura Book.ttf
> ```

Below is an MWE...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Futura Book.ttf}[
BoldFont = Futura Book Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont = Futura Book Italic BT.ttf,
BoldItalicFont = Futura Book Bold Italic.ttf]

\begin{document}
Some text in normalfont.
\bfseries{Some text in bfseries.}
\itshape{Some text in bfseries and italic.}
\end{document}
```

The output

[image]

---

**EDIT:**(31/8/2016)

I copied all my `.ttf` fonts into a folder and renamed them to remove spaces of any kind (just to be safe). I, then, edited my preamble to read

```
\setmainfont[
Path           = ../Fonts/Futura/FuturaBook/,
Extension      = .ttf,
BoldFont       = FuturaBookBold,
ItalicFont     = FuturaBookItalicBT,
BoldItalicFont = FuturaBookBoldItalic
]{FuturaBook}

\setmonofont{UbuntuMono-R}[
Path           = ../Fonts/ubuntu-font-family/,
Extension      = .ttf,
]
```

Now I don't have to install any font and the preamble is OS independent. Same preamble works from both Windows and Linux (Fedora23).

Comment: But these are not the files you asked about in your question. They have quite different names! Or did you rename them?

Comment: When I double clicked on the selected font files to install them, this is how they appeared in Windows/Fonts directory. :-(

I would prefer a solution which does not involve XeLaTeX.

Comment: I can't think why Windows would rename the files. But Windows is a strange OS which seems to often do unexpected and unwanted things, so it probably renames your files randomly. That is, if you say so, I have no reason not to believe you. I don't use it except on networked machines. Briefly. You can also use LuLaTeX. You can even use pdfLaTeX but you'd have to generate support files. (And you don't want to do that unless you really want to do that, if you see what I mean.)

Comment: :D
When those font files were previewed (before Installation), this was the name they had on the header/title bar. It was different from the actual file name. Windows sure is strange. When I open its fonts directory, it has a `Futura` font listed (`Futura Medium Regular`). However, I cannot find it using a DOS prompt (`cmd`). The 'parent' font file had an extension `.pfm`......wish I was making this up.

Comment: PFM/PFB are completely different kinds of things from TTF. The former are postscript type1. The latter are truetype. The PFM doesn't contain any glyphs. Only information about the metrics. (Equivalent to an AFM.) The PFB contains *only* glyphs. Re. weirdness: try dealing with traditional Mac fonts. In that case, if you aren't careful you lose the font completely because all the information is in a separate 'resource' 'fork' which is quite different from the regular file 'fork'. If you use standard tools to copy one, you lose the resource bit and your font disappears completely.

Comment: I have no idea about Windows/MikTeX, but TeXLive bundles `otfinfo` which you can use to get the various names related to the said font.